# Fallo en el diseño de formulario html

Tags: html, css, formularios

Estoy haciendo un formulario con el uso de las etiquetas , quiero que me quede así finalmente: [image: Ejemplo]
Todo estará con el estilo en el css, pero no consigo que me haga caso. Este es el index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formulario</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="form">
            <form method="POST" id="formulario" name="formulario" role="form">

                <!-- primera fila -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- primera columna -->
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    <br><br><br><br><input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
                    </div>
                    <!-- segunda columna -->
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                    </div>
                    <!-- tercera columna -->
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a title="Logytel" href="http://logytel.es"><img class="logytel" src="https://i2.wp.com/logytel.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cropped-LOGO_Logytel_2012_R_485C_24x10_8_Blanco.png" alt="Logytel" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- segunda fila -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- primera columna -->
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="check1"> Uno <br>
<span class="checkmark"></span>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="check2"> Dos <br>
<span class="checkmark"></span>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="check3"> Tres <br>
<span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- segunda columna -->
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="align: center;">Proyecto
                        <select class="custom-select">
                            <option>Opción 1</option>
                            <option>Opción 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <!-- tercera columna -->
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- tercera fila -->
            <div class="form-group" style="style=min-width: 100%">
                <div class="row">

                    <!-- segunda columna -->
                    <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 40%; ">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Mensaje:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                     <textarea name="contenido" id="contenido" class="form-control" rows="4"                    cols="50" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje aquí" style="background-color: white;"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>

            </div>

            </form>
            </div>

                <button id="myBtn" class="button" input type="submit" value="Enviar">Enviar</button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p id="resultado"> Tus datos han sido guardados correctamente.</p>
          </div>
        </div>



        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p id="resultado"> Tus datos han sido guardados correctamente.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('#formulario').submit(function(event) {
            // Obtenemos todos los datos
                var parametros = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
            // Lo enviamos mediante POST
                type: "POST",
            // A la URL
                url: "guardar.php",
            // Le pasamos los datos del formulario
                data: parametros,
                success: function(data) {
        // Abrimos el modal
                $("#myModal").modal("show");
            // Mostramos el resultado de la URL
                $('#resultado').html(data);
            // Reseteamos el formulario
                document.getElementById("formulario").reset();
            }
            });
        // Prevenimos que el botón submit recargue la página
            event.preventDefault();
        });
            </script>

        <script>
            var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
            /*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
            x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
            /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
            a = document.createElement("DIV");
            a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
            a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
            x[i].appendChild(a);
            /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
            b = document.createElement("DIV");
            b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
            for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
                /*for each option in the original select element,
                create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
                c = document.createElement("DIV");
                c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
                c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
                    and the selected item:*/
                    var y, i, k, s, h;
                    s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
                    h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
                for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                    if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                        s.selectedIndex = i;
                            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
                            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                            }
                                this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    h.click();
                    });
                b.appendChild(c);
            }
            x[i].appendChild(b);
            a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
                and open/close the current select box:*/
                e.stopPropagation();
                closeAllSelect(this);
                this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
                this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
                });
            }
            function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
            /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
            except the current select box:*/
            var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
            x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
            y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
            for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
                    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
                    arrNo.push(i)
                    } else {
                    y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
                    }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
                x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
                }
            }
        }
        /*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
        then close all select boxes:*/
        document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como se puede observar, el formulario obtiene los datos, los manda a un php aparte y los mete en la bd. También tiene un modal, que no me funciona del todo, y los estilos de las etiquetas no me hacen ni caso. Aquí el css:

```
    .form{
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:600px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    background-color:#EC2F2F;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top: 90px;
}

body{
    margin: 30px;
}
input[type=text],[type=email]{
    width:470px;
    height:35px;
    font: 14px normal normal uppercase arial;
}

input[type=checkbox]{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px!important;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
textarea{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font: 14px normal normal uppercase arial;
    resize: none;
    padding-top: 5px;   
}

input[type=submit]{
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:40px;
    border-radius:20px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    border:0px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    font: 14px black normal normal uppercase arial;
}

input {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    *overflow: hidden;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
    left: 9px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

/*CASILLA SELECCIONAR*/

/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: #C81A1A;
}

/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}

/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #C81A1A;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

/*BOTÓN ENVIAR*/

.button{
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 350px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}

.button:active {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
    box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
    transform: translateY(4px);
}

.logytel{
    float: right;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 8%;
    width:200px;
    height:81px;
}

/*MODAL*/

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #ff0000;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

No sé qué es lo que falla, si son las clases mal colocadas, el css, o el index. Si pueden ayudarme a dar con ello, lo agradecería muchísimo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: No se si te has fijado pero tienes etiquetas sin cerrar que pueden generar error, te dejo este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z40esu56/) en el que resalta en rojo tus lineas con error en el html

Comment: @NicolasOñate No me había percatado de esas etiquetas sin cerrar, ya edité el código de la pregunta sin esos fallos, pero el formulario me sigue apareciendo igual, sin los estilos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para empezar, tienes tantos problemas que mi recomendación es que empieces de nuevo ya que se ve que has cogido una plantilla o algo ya pre hecho y has tratado de adaptarlo en vano.

Tienes una mezcla de cosas ahí metidas que he intentado hacer algo pero está ya bastante infumable, ya que si tocas algo rompes otra cosa.

Mis recomendaciones son:

- Comprende el funcionamiento de [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/), ya que estas declarandolo en el html pero se ve que sin sentido. El elemento `col` es en si una clase css que divide en columnas tu html.
- Abuso del píxeles, para mi opinión, si deseas que te quede igual en cualquier pantalla, [usa unidades relativas](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).
- Usa las clases css para retocar y adaptar a tu formulario y no para forzarlo a tener una forma determinada, usando la potencia de bootstrap, ya que probablemente vuelvas a la misma situación si tratas de repetirlo.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo sobre cómo puedes empezar

```css
/* Uso css para detalles*/
.imagen {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 2%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-md-offset-7 col-sm-offset-7 col-xs-7 col-sm-5 col-md-5" >
  <label>Coloco a la derecha este texto</label>
  <div class="imagen">
  <img src="https://i2.wp.com/logytel.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cropped-LOGO_Logytel_2012_R_485C_24x10_8_Blanco.png" alt="Logytel"/>
  </div>
   </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Ejemplo</label>
    <input type="tex" class="form-control" id="ejemplo" placeholder="Nombre Ejemplo">
  </div>   
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> 1
    </label>   
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> 4
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> 2
    </label>   
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> 5
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> 3
    </label>   
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> 6
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Uso bootstrap para adaptar"></textarea>
  </div>
  
   <div class="col-md-offset-8 col-sm-offset-8 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Seguiré tu consejo y volveré a empezar de nuevo, ya comentaré si consigo lograr lo que quería, ¡gracias!

Comment: Aquí estaremos para ayudarte

Answer (score 4):

- Para empezar te falta un cierre de etiqueta en el `textarea`.
- Revisa los `div` ya que tienes mal dividida la pantalla para lo que quieres
  hacer y no se te va a organizar bien el `textarea` ni el botón.
- En la imagen que propones el `texarea` ocupa todo el ancho de la pantalla y
  lo tienes puesto para que ocupe un tercio ya que tienes el espacio
  dividido en 3.
- Te recomiendo que al `div` del cuerpo le metas un `margin: 10-30px` para que se separe 
  de los bordes de la pantalla.
- La lista de opciones tal y como la tienes solo te hace falta alinearlo al centro y 
  si quieres que el `texarea` te quede debajo centrado haz que ocupe todo el ancho o 
  ponlo en el `div` del centro y que ocupe el ancho del `div`.

De momento te recomiendo estos cambios, si después de esto tienes mas problemas comentalo.

Comment: -Ya cerré el textarea
-No sabría muy bien cómo dividirlo para que quede bien, aún me lío un poco con eso que dependa del número y tal.
- Ya está editado el textarea para que ocupe el ancho.
- Márgenes hechos

Ahora ya tengo mejor organizado todo, pero los checkbox y las opciones las quiero con un style, que se supone que ya está en el css con la clase, pero no aparece con ella. ¿Qué estará fallando?
Edité el código de la pregunta para que tenga los nuevos cambios.